# Finding $\det(-A^3B^TA^{-1})$ given $\det(A)$ and $\det(B)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

This is my first question, please forgive me if I mistake something.

The question I have is;

> Let A and B are square matrices of order 5. Find $\det(-A^3B^TA^{-1})$ while $ \det(A)=5 $ and $ \det(B)=1/8 $

What I did was put everything into place knowing $ \det(B)^T=\det(B)$ and what I got is something like this;

> $ \det((-125)(1/8)(1/5))\Rightarrow \det(-125/40) \Rightarrow 5(-125/40) \Rightarrow -125/8 $

but I am concerned that my knowledge here is not certain thus there is probably something I am missing. I would very much appreciate if you can just clear my mind on this by pointing what's wrong if there is anything. Again thank you.

EDIT:

With the information from the comments I came to this conclusion;

$ (-125)(1/8)(1/5) $ = $ -25/8 $

But what does the information of being order of five give me in this question if I don't need to factor it with five at the end? Is it just for the  $ \det(cA)=c^n\det(A)  $?

Comment: Since $\det(ABC)= \det A \det B \det C$ you can rearrange the square matrices to suit your computation. Also, $\det (cA) = c^n \det A$.

Comment: You have some basic computational mistakes.

Comment: Three wrong things a) You don't need a factor 5 at the end. b) it is not $B^T=B$ but $\det(B)=\det(B^T)$ c) (notations) you use "implies" symbols instead of "equal" signs...

Comment: @copper.hat The asker doesn't need $\det(cA)=c^n \det(A)$.

Comment: @JeanMarie: Sure they do. $c=-1$.

Comment: @copper.hat My bad...

Comment: @copper.hat I edited the post with the information from comments please let me know if it looks right this time. Thanks

Comment: But you haven't edited the post taking into account my comments... for example, matrix $B$ has no reason to be equal to $B^T$, It is only their determinants that are equal ...

Comment: @JeanMarie I am really sorry, I must have forgotten to edit that part while trying to figure out Mathjax. I have edited that part too right now. Thanks for reminding and clarifying

Comment: $(-125)(1/8)(1/5)\ne-25/4$.

Comment: Surprisingly the answer seems to be correct, however you have used some questionable maths to get to it, ie $B=B^T$,  not using the property mentioned by Jean Marie, and there is no need to write det((-125)(1/8)(1/5)), as these are just numbers, so you can just omit det

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks for pointing it out. I must have made a really bad calculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix, then
$$
\det(-A)=(-1)^n\det A
$$
because of the more general result you cite: $\det(cA)=c^n\det(A)$, with $c=-1$.

This follows from the fact that, denoting by $I$ the identity matrix, we have $cA=(cI)A$ and so Binet's theorem says that $\det(cA)=\det((cI)A)=\det(cI)\det(A)$. Now $cI$ is a diagonal matrix, so its determinant is the product of the entries along the diagonal, which are all equal to $c$ and there are $n$ of them. Thus $\det(cI)=c^n$.

In your case $n=5$, so you can say that
$$
\det(-A^3B^TA^{-1})=-\det(A^3B^TA^{-1})
$$
By Binet's theorem and taking into account that $\det(B^T)=\det(B)$ and $\det(A^{-1})=\det(A)^{-1}$,
\begin{align}
\det(-A^3B^TA^{-1})
&=-\det(A^3B^TA^{-1})\\[4px]
&=-\det(A^3)\det(B^T)\det(A^{-1})\\[4px]
&=-\det(A)^3\det(B)\det(A)^{-1}\\[4px]
&=-5^3\cdot\frac{1}{8}\cdot\frac{1}{5}=-\frac{25}{8}
\end{align}

There is no “multiplication by $5$” to do.

Comment: Can you name some bibliography that shows $det(-A) = (-1)^ndet(A)$? I don't recall this from when I studied determinants

Comment: @VictorS. I added the argument.

Answer (score 0):

By the properties of determinants, the determinant you're calculating is

$$\det(-A^3B^TA^{-1}) = (-1) \times det(A^3) \times det(B^T) \times det A^{-1} = (-1) \times det(A^2) \times det(B) $$ $$ = (-1) \times (det(A))^2 \times det(B) = \frac{-25}{8}$$

Notice that $$det(A^{-1}) = \frac{1}{det(A)}$$ and $det(A^3) = det(AAA) = det(A) \times det(A) \times det(A) $

Comment: But, how does $ \det(-A^3) $ becomes $ \det(A^3) $ what happens to the negative symbol?

Comment: I forgot about the - sign. Sorry

Comment: Also, do you know anything about the part of my question which I added to the last part about the rank of the matrix?

Comment: Should probably note that the - sign is appropriate only because the order of the matrix ($5$) is odd.  I'd add an exponent of $5$ to the initial $-1$ term in the first product.  If the order of the matrices were even, the - sign would go away.

Comment: You mean the order of the matrix. Be careful, the rank of a matrix and its order are not the same thing. About the fact that it is a 5 by 5 matrix: it doesn't matter since you already have the values for det(A) and det(B).

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, yes I was trying to mean the order of the matrix.